# Can you use AngularJS with Parse.com?

Tags: angularjs, backbone.js, cordova, parse-platform

I am new to phonegap development & I am trying to pick a framework to use. I'd like to use AngularJS as I've read good things about it, but I'd like it to work with Parse.com as a backend. I noticed that one Parse.com they don't specify any compatibility with Angular, and all their documentation and Javascript API requires Backbone.

I know AngularJS supports http, so I can communicate with Parse using the REST API. But is this going to end up being a mess & will I save myself time & stress if I use Backbone with the Parse.com Javascript API instead?

Answer (score 56):

I have not worked on Parse, but I believe as long there is a REST API available AngularJS can very well integrate with Parse.com. These links substantiate that fact

https://parse.com/questions/does-any-know-of-any-angularjs-sites-that-are-built-with-parse-that-are-open-source

http://brandid.github.io/parse-angular-demo/#/

Said that, AngularJS is a very capable framework with a steep learning curve. The simple stuff is simple but one needs to put ones head down and start learning the not so simple stuff like [directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) once one starts building any decent size application. The more you invest in learning AngularJS the more rewarding it becomes.

It has a very clean separation in terms of view and code. The code is further organized into modules, factories, services, controllers, directive, filters etc.

But still nothing stops you from creating a mess with the implementation :) What I have realized over the time is even if you create mess within AngularJS the effects are localized rather than affecting the complete application, due to the modular nature of Angular.

I suggest you try creating or looking at some samples with AngularJS (such as [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/))

[This](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2439-My-Experience-With-AngularJS-The-Super-heroic-JavaScript-MVW-Framework.htm) is how i felt learning and implementing AngularJS solutions
[image]

Answer (score 18):

Thanks for bring up our Parse x AngularJS boilerplate - we've just updated it today too.

Our entire site [getbrandid.com](http://www.getbrandid.com) is built with Parse x AngularJS and no servers of our own.

We built this boilerplate after because having spent a few years building BRANDiD, we had a lot of best practices to share with the Parse and AngularJS communities. We think it is a match made in heaven, and is the fastest way to build powerful complex, highly maintainable serverless apps.

We've basically extended the Parse SDK to support AngularJS bindings, we've eliminated a ton of boilerplate code, and most importantly, we've established an architecture for large serverless apps using Parse and Angular.

I highly encourage you to check it out -

[Parse x AngularJS Boilerplate](http://brandid.github.io/parse-angular-demo)

Comment: I just checked out BrandID and I LOVED IT! It's so cool!

How come you guys extended the SDK rather than use Parse via REST?

Comment: Just a side note. Your site breaks if adblock is enabled.

Comment: Yup. Your link is broken! :(

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 11):

Actually `Parse`'s documentation does not say that you have to use `Parse` with `Backbone`, it just says that some stuff are *compatible* with `Backbone` classes, like the [`Collections`](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#collections) object, which might be useful ONLY IF you use `Backbone`.

The big hassle of using 3rd party stuff inside angular is its lifecycle, as it uses [POJO](http://ajaxian.com/archives/return-of-the-pojo-plain-ole-javascript)s and only watches for changes in these objects at specific points in time - Check the [`Scope Life Cycle` documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#what-are-scopes_scope-life-cycle) for more info.

Given that, when `Parse` returns its callbacks, `AngularJS` might no longer be observing those  `Parse` objets, so you need a way of telling angular that thing changed, and you have to do it inside the digest loop, for example using [`$scope.$apply`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24apply)

I created a [small wrapper for `Parse.Query` and `Parse.Object`](https://github.com/felipesabino/angular-parse) to avoid the need for `$scope.$apply` all the time, let me know if you find it useful: https://github.com/felipesabino/angular-parse

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found to communicate with the parse.com backend is to use the [jimrhoskins/angular-parse](https://github.com/jimrhoskins/angular-parse) Angularjs module that replaces the (backbone) ParseSDK.

Ads instant :-) I included it in this [angular/parse boilerplate](https://github.com/jbeurel/angular-parse-boilerplate).

Answer (score 1):

We've been using this method fairly frequently. We decided to document our experience. Its a [2 part series on building angular apps with a parse backend](https://www.enolalabs.com/blog/archives/wrapping-third-party-libraries-in-angular-factories). Hope it helps!