# When to use ASP.net MVC instead of Angular or React js with REST?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I mean to ask is, what are the advantages and disadvantages of using ASP.net MVC as compared to Angular or React js with REST?

Comment: Here is the similar post.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23076670/asp-net-mvc-5-vs-angularjs-asp-net-webapi

Answer (score -1):

You will find this question asked a million times but I want to give my contribute.

I recently choosed to use both approaches for a project. I am using ASP.NET MVC for backoffice (admin stuff) and Angular for the frontoffice with an ASP.NET REST API.

**Why?**

- For the *backoffice* I mostly need CRUD operations, I am not too concerned about having an awesome UI and I need it ready ASAP.
- For the *frontoffice* I am a lot more concerned about UI/UX. It is important that customers have the best experience possible, so I want to invest more time there.

Also, having a separate project for the frontend and a REST API for the backend will make development a lot easier, especially if you have a team.

**Conclusion**

If I need something fast, like a prototype, I may choose ASP.NET MVC. In all other cases I always prefer using Angular + REST API.