# Does parse.com javascript sdk play nicely with angular?

Tags: angularjs, backbone.js, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I'm evaluating parse.com as a backend for a cordova/ionic mobile project and was curious about peformance or potential conflicts with using parse's javascript sdk.  I'd rather have all the features of their javascript sdk but am wondering if ionic's angular based framework will have conflicts or slow down performance when combined with parse.com's backbone based solution.

Will it get bloated and slow or will they both run nice and lean without conflicts?  Any showcase apps out there that use both?

Comment: yes you can and I think there is alot of good material here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556712/can-you-use-angularjs-with-parse-com